# How to control the arrow length of vector field markers in the layer list legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, markers, qgis-3, vector-field

In QGIS 2.14.5 LTR (and recently in QGIS 3.0) I've set up a beautiful map design with a graduated renderer and vector field markers for each value range (arrow length is directly proportional to stream velocity, which ranges from 0.001 -~5m/s).

This worked great, but I wonder if I missed a setting to shorten the arrows in the legend. With a 'normal' width layer window, the class values cannot be seen:

Units: *millimeter*

[image]

My first guess was, that it has sth. to do with switching arrow length, line width units from millimeter to map units, but this doesn't affect the legend:

Units: *map units*

[image]

**UPDATE**

Issue still persists in QGIS 3.0.

I created a screencast to visualize this: https://youtu.be/oxJ3tGXFB18

[image]

In properties / symbology the symbols render correctly:

[image]

**Note** that the layer list displays the markers correctly, when duplicating the layer or applying changes to the style as long as layers panel width does not change.

Comment: Can reproduce it (QGIS 2.14.5. Linux Mint 18). Maybe some _Layers panel_ bug. However, it doesn't affect _Legend_ item in _Composer manager_

Comment: I can confirm that there is an issue when using map units. Ran into it myself. Haven't checked yet if it has been reported.

Comment: Maybe you should make a bug report. https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Comment: I made a [bug report for this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19354). Most of the text of the bug report is directly quoted from this post. Please review the bug report and edit it if I made any mistakes or left out anything important.

Comment: It seems there is some interest among the QGIS community in fixing this bug. There's a request to add "a small dataset + QGIS3 project file with the styles used" to the bug report to aid in testing. @JochenSchwarze Is it possible for you to provide that information?

Comment: @csk yes, just did so. thx for raising the issue!

Comment: i'm just beginning on this discussion and forum.
I would like to use this thread to request or download the module that allows to plot vectors from a CSV (vector field renderer on QGIS 2.18.13)
I switched to QGIS 3.2.2 but couldn't find this extension.
I see in Jochen's question that despite everything, you use something that looks like it on QGIS3. Can you tell me where to find this module?
Sorry, I tried to look on the forum to find out if the question had already been asked but I found nothing to that effect.
Best regards L. PREVORS

Comment: @PREVORS Welcome to GIS.SE! It's neither a module or an extension, you can simply select 'Vector field marker' in a point layers style panel in QGIS. It would go too far to explain it here, but consider to ask a question like 'How to apply vector field style to point data in QGIS' or sth. like that if things are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't exist that option, but... you can use intern tools to achieve that results. I made it with dots but you can apply this tools to your thing. Follow this:

1. First set manually the size of the symbol.
2. Go to the properties of each element and define a function that "do your thing" (in your project, it changes the line size with stream speed). This function will change the size of the element while the legend element freezes.

[image]

[image]

3. There you go. Legends would stay still while your elements change their size following your function.

[image]